# Installing Virtual box and genymotion on a 32bit running khali linux as the operating software

Tags: android

Hi friends i have recently installed Android Studio IDE on my laptop which is a 32 bit machine running **Khali linux** as the operating system but its refusing to install both *virtual box and genymotion*.**I have tried to downloading several tutorials for getting a proper virtual box relevant to my machine and operating software but it hasnt worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to /etc/apt/sources file then add this line :

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
```

Then download the package from Oracle (i.e. Virtualbox)

```
sudo wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now just type in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

You're done ! now type `virtualbox` to run the Virtualbox and Enjoy

Comment: you said i should navigate to the /etc/apt/sources files, what command do i type in to do this.i recently started using linux so im not so familia with all the commands,please assist.

Comment: 'cd /etc/apt/' and then use  'nano sources'